# RxWorker In Background thread

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am developing an application which will constantly upload images to the server, I have implemented the Rxworker from workmanager, I have written the code for uploading, but when the worker is running im getting exception as networkOnMainthread.

Can anyone explain how to run RxWorker in the background thread, by default RxWorker will run on main thread https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/RxWorker

Comment: Could you please provide the code within `createWork()`?